# Seeking carbon geospatial data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, geocoding, environment

Is there a easy way to access and query carbon data such as the data that comes from OCO-2 satellite?

I’m trying to find a easy way of quantifying the carbon emissions within a certain area.

Ideally I enter an address or coordinates and I get the data. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem like there is very geograpically detailed data easily available, but at the country level, Our World In Data has sources listed here: https://github.com/owid/co2-data

There are also several sources from NOAA that may include satellite data - but I'm pretty sure that observational data like this won't account for the differences between human emissions and other factors like seasonal variation due to plant growth:
https://gml.noaa.gov/aftp/data/